Understanding radiation efficiency and operation of 35 foot whip antenna in the 2MHz to 30 MHz band
Some 35 foot whips are designed to operate in the 2 MHz to 30 MHz band e.g. Valcom 35-Ft Aluminum Whip Antenna AS-3772 B/U.
The length of whip antenna is around wavelength divided by 14.
Can anyone explain to me, how transmission is possible with whip length much lower than quarter wavelength?
Also how to achieve a good radiation efficiency over the large 2MHz to 30 MHz bandwidth?

Is ground connection mentioned? A whip on its own is only part of the radiator. Significant power might be lost in poor grounding. Radiation pattern is also affected.

Your assumptions are incorrect. A 35-foot whip is longer than a 1/4 wavelength for all frequencies above 6.7 MHz. At 30 MHz, the antenna is about one full wavelength. An antenna less than ¼ wavelength is going to be a low impedance. An antenna at least a ¼ wavelength or greater will vary from 35 to several thousand ohms. The efficiency greatly depends on your ground losses. You never said what kind of ground plane you intend to construct.
A good tuner can tune a fish, bicycle wheel, or ham sandwich. It works well on a ham sandwich, getting it nice and hot.

As you mentioned impedance is low for frequency below 6.7MHz for antenna height less than 1/4 wavelength. Is it possible to improve the efficiency by design of proper matching network that results in VSWR  below 2.0? In other words for short antenna like 35 feet whip at HF band of 2MHz to 6.7MHz, is it just design of proper matching network  a key to get good efficiency?

OP will find it instructive to examine the manual for this antenna (https://www.valcommfg.ca/_files/ugd/fcd44a_0d04f0d8945f4116b6f95ca4725481e2.pdf).
Briefly, it is intended to be used with a "tuner"- that is, a matching network. Not surprising as the impedance of the antenna will vary over the 2-30 MHz range from capacitive to low value resistive to inductive to high value resistive... That is, if OP is thinking that a matching network with no adjustable components will work over the entire frequency range...not gonna happen.
With a good matching network, most of the applied power will indeed be radiated although at some frequencies this might be...challenging.
By the way, this antenna is intended for use in naval applications (that is, on a ground plane). It's mighty big for consumer use and rated for far more power than needed for consumer use.
